# Unresolved external symbol with the THOR SFML extension

Tags: c++, linker-errors, sfml, thor

I want to use [Thor library](http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/) in a Visual Studio C++ project and I followed the instructions on the THOR website.
I think I linked the right directories to my project, the same thing I do to link SFML to my projects, and when I include files from the THOR library it doesn't show any error in my project.
However, I can't run my project because I have several errors that say:

> "unresolved external symbol [...]"

For example:
[image: Error]

Here's how I linked the THOR library to my project: 
[image: Link to THOR include directory]

If someone knows how to address the issue, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: I tried again to install thor, the first time I hadn't built the "INSTALL" build in Release mode. This time I did but I get 4 "unresolved external symbol" errors"...

Comment: The paths/directories that you've included, one of them is to the "src" folder of the Thor-library? It's probably the path that we can't see in the last picture - D:\Programmes\thor-v2.0-sdk\src .

Comment: No, the last link is the path to the SFML include directory

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't link Thor. You added the include files but not the library files.

In Visual Studio, you have to go to Linker -> General in the same window you screenshoted, add the path to the lib files in the "Additional Library Directories" field for All configurations (I guess the path should be something like `D:\Programmes\thor-v2.0-sdk\lib`). Then, in Linker -> Input, you add `thor` for Release configuration (or `thor-d` for Debug) in the "Additional Dependencies".